# Trying to set up a second router as a repeater

Tags: router, repeater

I have a Linksys e2500 running as my main router. I don't get wifi in my room, so I am trying to connect a second router to extend the range. Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to set up my Netgear WNR1000v3 as a repeater. Would anybody be able to explain to me how to do this, as I am completely lost?

Answer (score 1):

That particular router, the Netgear WNR1000, might actually support it, but only in Wireless N mode. According to this chart on Page 1 there is a "repeater mode (WDS)":

http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNR1000V2/wnr1000_ds_29jan09.pdf

Also this guide might help you get started as well:

http://www.ehow.com/how_7439379_set-up-netgear-repeater.html

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest an easier way to do it would be to set up your Netgear as an Access Point by running an Ethernet cable closer to your room, or even using a Powerline Networking Adapter to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are wifie xtenders from various suppliers, including [Netgear](http://www.netgear.com.au/home/products/wireless-range-extenders/) and [Linksys](http://store.linksys.com/products/cisco-linksys-range-extenders_stcVVcatId554677VVviewcat.htm), but the your routers won't work that way.

EDIT
There is router firmware from DD-WRT that lets you update a router so it can act as a repeater. The WNR1000 is supported but only with f/w v2, not v3. The Linksys is not supported. Here is their [list of supported routers.](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database)